# How to read csv since header inclusively in apache commons csv?

Tags: java, csv, parsing, header, apache-commons-csv

Following approach allows to read with skipping header:

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().parse(in);

for (CSVRecord record : records) {
     //here first record is not header
}
```

How can I read csv since header line inclusively ?

P.S.

approach:

```
CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().withSkipHeaderRecord(false).parse(in)
```

doesn't work and has the same behaviour

Comment: @Berger, I corrected code a bit. Yes - it is actual code now

Comment: **public final class CSVParser implements Iterable<CSVRecord>, Closeable {**

Comment: This won't be an easy task, if you have a look at the `initializeHeader` method that `CSVParser` calls from its constructor, you will see that `nextRecord()` gets called and skips the first line in your case (`format.getHeader()` is an array of size 0 here). See. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html  . Why do you have this requirement ?

Comment: @Berger I did workaround and invoked **records.getHeaderMap().keySet()** before loop to get headers. I need to do some additional check before processing.

Comment: Okay that seemed to be the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

For me the followings all seem to have the header record as the first one (using `commons-csv` 1.5):

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withSkipHeaderRecord().parse(in); //???
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withSkipHeaderRecord(false).parse(in); 
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withSkipHeaderRecord(true).parse(in); //???
```

And as you have stated the following does NOT seem to have the header record as the first one:

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().parse(in); //???
```

It is beyond my understanding why `withSkipHeaderRecord()` and `withSkipHeaderRecord(true)` do include the header while `withHeader()` does not; seems to be the opposite behaviour as to what the method names suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The `withHeader()` method tells the parser that the file has a header. Perhaps the method name is confusing.

The `withFirstRecordAsHeader()` method may also be useful.

From the [CSVFormat (Apache Commons CSV 1.8 API)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html) JavaDoc page:

> ### Referencing columns safely
>
> If your source contains a header record, you can simplify your code and safely reference columns, by using [`withHeader(String...)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withHeader-java.lang.String...-) with no arguments:
>
> ```
> CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader();
> ```
>
> This causes the parser to read the first record and use its values as column names. Then, call one of the [`CSVRecord`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html) get method that takes a String column name argument:
>
> ```
> String value = record.get("Col1");
> ```
>
> This makes your code impervious to changes in column order in the CSV file.